# What is the risk of sharing the client_secret.json in a public repo?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-sheets-api, google-oauth

I have a python script which writes data into a public google sheets file and for using the google sheets API I need to have a user authorize my script. I want to share the script with others and thus I'm considering sharing the client_secret.json as well, but I'm struggling at understanding the security-risks involved in this.

As far as I understand OAuth2, by providing client_secret.json my script authenticates itself and then a user authorizes the script to write data on the user's behalf, right?

Thus, am I correct, that the worst thing which could happen when I would share the client_secret.json, is that someone would exploit my service to write data into sheets (only his/her own or into public ones) by using my script's quota?

Comment: You give someone the ability to write an app which does whatever they want, so long as it uses the particular APIs which you have enabled for that project. So if you use the Drive API, they can prompt the user to authorize their app with the full Drive access scope, and then delete every single file they want. To google, you are the one who is doing that, as the requests are authenticated with your credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user @thehowch stated and as I understand the whole procedure, the very main risk of sharing a client_secret.json is that of opening an attack vector for phishing attacks, since someone could just copy the client_secret and then present him/herself as a trustworthy authority where users would give their authorizations to it and thus would open their google drive to the attacker.

Also quota-usage of Google's API would be registered on the google project account which possesses the client_secret. Thus an attacker could just block our usage by exhausting the quota. Of course this risk is nothing compared to the phishing attack. Just as a side-node for the sake of completeness.